# New Intel i350 NIC not detected by system, but appears in lspci - Possible Intel IGB issue?

Tags: centos, networking, drivers, network-interface, networkmanager

I'm running into an issue where a new network card isn't being automatically detected by the OS. I recently purchased an Intel I350 gigabit network card. *I have purchased this card before and I have used it in other systems with the same OS with no issues.* This is the card https://ark.intel.com/products/84805/Intel-Ethernet-Server-Adapter-I350-T4V2.

The odd thing is that this card is being detected by Windows, but not Oracle Linux, CentOS Live, or Ubuntu Live.

"nmcli d" output

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION
eno2    ethernet  connected     eno2
eno1    ethernet  disconnected  --
lo      loopback  unmanaged     --
```

These are the onboard adapters. The 4 Intel ones are not detected.

"lspci | grep Network" output

```
b3:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
b3:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
b3:00.2 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
b3:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
```

The OS appears to at least know of the existence of the PCI card.

This is the output of "lshw -class network"

```
*-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GBASE-T
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:19:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 09
       serial: ac:1f:6b:4c:ff:04
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=i40e driverversion=1.5.16-k firmware=3.1d 0x80000827 1.1638.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:54 memory:c4000000-c4ffffff memory:c5008000-c500ffff memory:c5d80000-c5dfffff memory:c5010000-c508ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GBASE-T
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:19:00.1
       logical name: eno2
       version: 09
       serial: ac:1f:6b:4c:ff:05
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=i40e driverversion=1.5.16-k duplex=full firmware=3.1d 0x80000827 1.1638.0 ip=192.168.127.36 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:54 memory:c3000000-c3ffffff memory:c5000000-c5007fff memory:c5d00000-c5d7ffff
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:b3:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fbd00000-fbdfffff memory:fbe8c000-fbe8ffff memory:fbe00000-fbe7ffff memory:fbe90000-fbeaffff memory:fbeb0000-fbecffff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:b3:00.1
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fbc00000-fbcfffff memory:fbe88000-fbe8bfff memory:fbed0000-fbeeffff
  *-network:2 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:b3:00.2
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fbb00000-fbbfffff memory:fbe84000-fbe87fff
  *-network:3 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.3
       bus info: pci@0000:b3:00.3
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fba00000-fbafffff memory:fbe80000-fbe83fff
```

I noticed that the card is detected here as well, but it is listed as "UNCLAIMED". How do I go about making the system "claim" the card?

I have tried using the drivers listed from Intel's website, but it didn't seem to help. I could've also have been doing something wrong too. I don't have much experience with linux drivers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems manually updating the firmware on the network card itself made the card visible to the OS.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and I tried to update firmware manually. I saw two ports by command "bootutil64e". But after I run "bootutil64e -UP=PXE -ALL -FILE=../BootIMG.FLB", I got "Cannot initialize adapter" with both ports. Same result with "bootutil64e -ALL -defcfg". What should I do now? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I added an answer which worked for me from a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was from a few years ago, but I have notes of the fix... I did the following:

Create a file under the directory /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/  called "90-carrier.conf"

```
# touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-carrier.conf

Modify the file and add the following two lines to it and save your changes:

# vi  /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-carrier.conf

[main]
ignore-carrier=no

Restart the NetworkManager service:

# systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with Intel I219-LM rev 11 device on new CentOS 7.9.2009 install.

The fix using file /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-carrier.conf did not work for me.

I also downloaded Intel release_27.6 package but running nvmupdate64e did not find the NIC either.

Any other proposed method?  Thanks!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/428279)